# mongoid enum ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm using `mongoid-enum` gem exactly like the [spec](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid_enum/Mongoid/Enum)

```
class AdVariation
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Enum

  enum medium: [:google, :facebook]
end
```

and when I run `AdVariation.new` I get:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)
```

The [repo](https://github.com/thetron/mongoid-enum) isn't maintained and doesn't answer questions/bugs

Did anyone stumble upon this?

```
$ bundle show | grep mongoid
* mongoid (5.4.0)
* mongoid-enum (0.4.0)
```

Comment: Do you have a backtrace of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out the documentation on the gem is wrong. The right way is:

```
enum :medium, [:google, :facebook], default: nil
```